# How to make a file appear to 'ls' in xv6 QEMU?

Tags: c, qemu, ls, xv6

I'm messing around with xv6 in QEMU, and I made a new file in the directory I'm in, and when I'm in QEMU and type `ls` the file isn't listed.  In fact, lots of files aren't listed, and I can't figure out why it lists the ones it does.  It seems to only list compiled `.c` files, and for some reason a README, but not the compiled `.c` file I just made.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because you forgot to add your .c file in the Makefile. Suppose test.c is the file you want to add. You need to add it in the Makefile under UPROGS as:

```
UPROGS=\
....
....
_test\
```

and under EXTRA as:

```
EXTRA=\
mkfs.c ulib.c user.h cat.c echo.c forktest.c grep.c kill.c\
ln.c ls.c mkdir.c rm.c stressfs.c usertests.c wc.c zombie.c\
printf.c umalloc.c **test.c**\
README new.txt dot-bochsrc *.pl toc.* runoff runoff1 runoff.list\
.gdbinit.tmpl gdbutil\
```

If you want to add generic files like README to Xv6, refer to this question:

[Add a generic file in xv6 makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250441/add-a-generic-file-in-xv6-makefile/47312565#47312565)